# Подсчёт всех полей, а не одного с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, калькулятор

Здравствуйте. Пока новичок с JS и jQuery, не могу разобраться, как можно расширить мой скрипт для всех строк в таблице, чтобы подсчитывалась стоимость всех товаров в таблице. Сейчас почему-то скрипт отлично работает с первой строкой (первым товаром), а на другие не распространяется.

Привожу код.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Штрих-код</th>
                <th>Наименование</th>
                <th>Цена</th>
                <th>Количество</th>
                <th>Стоимость</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">2</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Мужское портмоне «Pidengbao»</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span id="price">1190</span> ₽</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="col-md-1"><input type="number" id="qty" value="1" min="0" class="form-control" name="2" <="" td="">
                        </td><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span id="total">3570</span> ₽</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">6</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Сумка «Polo» в клетку</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span id="price">3990</span> ₽</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="col-md-1"><input type="number" id="qty" value="1" min="0" class="form-control" name="6" <="" td="">
                        </td><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span id="total">3990</span> ₽</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">8</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Сумка «Polo» классическая коричневая средняя</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span id="price">2990</span> ₽</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="col-md-1"><input type="number" id="qty" value="1" min="0" class="form-control" name="8" <="" td="">
                        </td><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span id="total">2990</span> ₽</td>
                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
    </table>
```

И сам скрипт:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#qty").change(function() {
            var price = $("#price").text() * 1;
            var qty = $("#qty").val() * 1;
            var total;

            total = price * qty;

            $("#total").text(total);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Вот скриншот (первая строка подсчитывается, остальные нет):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Вашем html повторяются `id` DOM элементов, что нарушает спецификацию html. Естественно, `$("#qty")`, `$("#price")`, `$("#total")` находят только первый элемент с соответствующим `id`.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Исправил на `class`, но всё равно неверно подсчитывает. Сейчас, я так понял, скрипт объединяет все цены (119039902990) и умножает их на значение количества из первого инпута. Мне нужно, чтобы каждая стоимость подсчитывалась отдельно - цена конкретного товара умножалась на принадлежащий ей инпут с количеством. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что за аттрибут   `<=""`? Смотрите ответ.

Comment: Что-то от хрома, скорее всего от расширения какого-то. Просто копировал из него. Но это не важно, разобрался, всё работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем html повторяются `id` DOM элементов, что нарушает спецификацию html. Естественно, `$("#qty")`, `$("#price")`, `$("#total")` находят только первый элемент с соответствующим `id`. Замените аттрибут `id` в этих элементах на `class` и:

```
    $(".qty").change(function() {
        var price = $(this).parent().find(".price").text() * 1;
        var qty = $(this).val() * 1;
        var total = price * qty;

        $(this).parent().find(".total").text(total);
    });
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо. Но пришлось сделать два parent, привожу код:
`<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
   $(".qty").change(function() {
    var price = $(this).parent().parent().find(".price").text() * 1;
    var qty = $(this).val() * 1;
    var total = price * qty;

    $(this).parent().parent().find(".total").text(total);
   });
  });
 </script>`
Разобрался! Ура :)

Comment: Пардон, упустил. Тогда используйте `$(this).closest("tr")` или `$(this).closest(".product")` - назначив `class="product"` рядам таблицы, вместо `$(this).parent().parent()`. Happy coding.